# What is the first leap year after 1 AD to start on a monday?

Tags: date

I'm asking because it makes some things really nice for some math I'm doing.

I'll post it when I find it if no one gets to it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first leap year to start on a Monday was [the year 20](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20).

Answer (score 2):

According to Mathematica's "`DayOfWeek`" function, 20 AD is the first such leap year.

```
DayOfWeek[{20,1,1}] == Monday
```

But there are a lot of caveats about what to consider to be the day of the week before Europe switched from the Julian to Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](http://cobalt.archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/petcal.pl?century=0000s&day=Thursday&month=February&date=29) the year 20. I think it is using the Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score -1):

Argh, I read over the "leap year" part of the sentence. So it's not [the year 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3), but 20. Of course, this is using the [Julian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar), currently we use the [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar). The Julian calendar had leap days (on February 24), but not the exception every 100 years. See [Proleptic Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) for more information, including the differences over time.

Comment: He said using the Julian calendar.

Comment: Julian and Gregorian should be the same in year 20, Gregorian only changed the century rules.

Comment: As it happens the Gregorian calendar has year 1 as starting on a Monday (.NET's DateTime starts on a Monday :)